# configure: error: Unable to find JDK Headers

Tags: java

I am a novice here.I am trying to execute this command :

```
./configure --without-activemq --with-jdk=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include --prefix=/usr/local --with-icu=/usr
```

On doing so, I am getting this error :

```
checking jni.h usability... no
checking jni.h presence... no
checking for jni.h... no
configure: error: Unable to find JDK Headers
```

I have installed open-jdk-8 and my current JAVA_HOME = usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Can someone please tell me how I can rectify this error ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Probably need to drop /include from the —with-jdk option

Comment: @Strelok, I am getting the same error even after dropping /include

Comment: Are the headers present in that folder? Did you check?

Comment: Yes, I did. The jni.h file is present in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include .

Comment: What are you building anyway?